# Vuetify VComboBox not showing options in Web Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue component that I build as a web component through the vue-cli-service. I have had a few issues with vuetify while trying to do this. The last one I have to fix is an issue where my v-combobox does not display the drop down menu for choosing options.

Here is how I have it set up.

Component:

```
<v-combobox
   v-model="dataType"
   label="Select an interaction type"
   :items="types"
></v-combobox>
```

data:

```
types: ['option1', 'option2']
```

I am importing and including all components al a carte like suggested in many tutorials on forcing vuetify to work inside a web component like this:

```
<script>
import { VCombobox } from "vuetify/lib";
import vuetify from "../../../plugins/vuetify"
export default {
  name: "SecondaryPathwayForm",
  components: {
    VCombobox,
  },
  vuetify,
}
</script>
```

I have been able to get all relevant CSS and styles to work, but I cannot figure out why the options wont display under the combobox. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: This answer provided a solution for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185944/1274852