# Vuetify data-app after runnin production build on webpack 4

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm currently trying to build a Vue application with Vue as a framework for material design, however when I build my project I get a warning which permits me from seeing any of the built UI.

The error is this:

> [Vuetify] Unable to locate target [data-app]
>
> found in
>
> VDialog > VApp > App at App.vue > Root

I can't even run an example pages that are prepared for them to run.

I've tried  and data-app attribute in the element, but withouth any success.

If anyone had faced this issue it would be great if you could share the solution or guide me towards more help.

Comment: Can you please provide code where you are mounting your vue App?

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuetify-data-app-true-and-problems-rendering-v-dialog-in-unit-tests/27495

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuetify issue with v-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596881/vuetify-issue-with-v-menu)

Comment: I wasn't able to solve that problem, while trying to sort it out, I figured out my docker container for production environment wasn't syncing well my ./dist folder to the workdir which was in docker.