# Production build only error: Vuetify Unable to locate target data-app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I only get this error in the production build. [image]

I have read this [doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#menu-dialog-navigation-drawer-are-not-opening-properly-) and this related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596881/vuetify-issue-with-v-menu) but I still cannot get it to work. `<v-app>` is wrapped around the `v-dialog` why does it still complain?

Here is my code

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-dialog max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          Create
        </v-card-title>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```
\\main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import store from "./store/store";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
import App from "./App.vue";

Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

Comment: try adding another `template` around the `v-dialog`

Comment: The stacktrace shows an unusual component hierarchy that contains two `VApp`'s (there should only be one).

Comment: I had the same error when using Vuetify with Vuepress, presumably because it does not use the `VApp`. This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990132/9035706

Answer (score 42):

Add `data-app` attribute to the target

```
<div data-app>
      <MyComponent />
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this necessary?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me, but I am also curious as to what `data-app` actually is for? I can't seem to find any info about it.

Comment: @Kellen Vuetify requires your app to be wrapped around by v-app which then adds this data-app automatically for you. So ideally you should do that, otherwise doing it manually as suggested here should work too.

Answer (score 13):

add v-app

```
<v-app>
      <MyComponent />
</v-app>
```

Comment: I like this answer more. IMHO, I think, v-app might likely the part of a public API. See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-app/

Even though, data-app attribute mentioned in other answer works. I couldn't find it in Vuetify docs (Please feel to comment here and let me know if such a thing exist).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry its my bad. The reason I had this error is because there were two `<script>` tags in the html that imported vue js files. So it was running twice. I removed one of the tags and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when using vuetify via laravel-mix and vuetifyjs-mix-extension. I added in the config webpack.mix.js vuetify-loader:

```
mix.js('src/js/app.js', 'js').vuetify('vuetify-loader').vue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue, just add v-app to your App.vue main template

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <MyComponent />
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it into the

```
<div data-app> or <v-app>
```

containers.

Personally I hate to use **v-app** because it adds some undesired styles.